# How to generate web service client in eclipse from a given physical wsdl file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to generate a web service client in eclipse from a given wsdl file which is not hosted at the moment yet . I'm trying to generate the proxy and do coding while it host in future for production .

I went through to some tutorial , they simply state create a "`Dynamic Web Project`" and within that add new "`Web Service Client`" , I do the same , But in that wizard, eclipse ask me to put the service address as bellow :

[image]

I tried to add physical location of the file , But it didn't work .

( the picture is not mine , I took it from the [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777036/Consuming-WCF-Service-in-Java-Client) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **file:/**

instead of **http://**

Greetings

Comment: Please expand your answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the WSDL file into the project folder and in eclipse right click on the WSDL file, then you can see Web Services and the generate client menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use: **file:///C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/mywebservicewsdlfile.wsdl**